# dlib build error in qt widget application

Tags: qt, linker, dlib

well I built dlib for qt mingw32 in windows and using it completely when I add a qt console project but when I want to use dlib in qtwidget application when I include the dlib headers to qt .pro file it gives this error

crt0_c.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

and libs in .pro file are like this

```
INCLUDEPATH+=..\include

LIBS += -L"..\lib"
LIBS += -ldlib
LIBS += -lmingw32
LIBS += -lOle32
LIBS += -lOleaut32
LIBS += -lm
LIBS += -ldinput8
LIBS += -lcomctl32

LIBS += -ldxguid
LIBS += -ldxerr8
LIBS += -luser32
LIBS += -lgdi32
LIBS += -lwinmm
LIBS += -limm32
LIBS += -lole32
LIBS += -loleaut32
LIBS += -lshell32
LIBS += -lversion
LIBS += -luuid

LIBS += -lglut32
LIBS += -lopengl32
LIBS += -lglu32
LIBS += -lgdi32
LIBS += -lwinmm
LIBS += -lws2_32
```

since i am using it in console projects without error it is kind of strange what causes the error
Can anybodey help?

I am using windows 7

Comment: what's your os win/linux?

Comment: i am using windows 7(added to question thank u)

Comment: Are you using QtCreator if yes add compile output red part, that shows why linker can not find reference

Comment: yes i am using QtCreator added that up in the question here crt0_c.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `WinMain@16' is error

Comment: So print compile output texts in bottom of main window in QtCreator or by press Alt+4 you ca see it and compiler erros

Comment: it turns out the problem was -lmingw32 library which compiler could not find and when i removed this line from .pro file the error disappeared and now i can run the code in qtwidget application but i don't know why compiler can't find lmingw32, thank saeed for help

Comment: Your welcome, sometimes compiler mix path to libraries with certain path in environments variable. That's interesting to give useful hints